# How to Get Correct Value Of php Timestamp

Tags: php

Here is my code of timestamp

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$date=date("l, F \ j,Y, h:i:s A");

echo date_timestamp_get($date);
```

but I don't get value of the timestamp.

I want format looks this it `1516426272898`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below code

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$date=date("l, F \ j,Y, h:i:s A");


echo strtotime($date);
```